# does opera/IE7+ have support for addClass/removeClass in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, opera, addclass

I have CSS for list tags that emulate buttons, as follows:

Before addClass is called (and ideally, what removeClass should return to)

```
#content_navigation li {
background-color:#C7C7C7;
border:2px outset black;
text-align:center;
font-weight:400;
}
```

After addClass('clicked'); is called

```
#content_navigation li.clicked {
background-color:#EFEFEF;
border:1px inset black;
font-weight:700;
}
```

My JQuery code (for one button):

```
$('#pass_settings_btn').click(function() {
$('#pass_settings_btn').addClass('clicked');
$('li:not(#pass_settings_btn').removeClass('clicked');
```

In Firefox, this works perfectly. but in Opera/IE7 (the only ones I have to test on, apart from Firefox 5), but buttons don't go back to their original states. The original CSS isn't "coming through" after removeClass is called. How can I fix this (hopefully without a browser specific hack?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

`$('li:not(#pass_settings_btn').removeClass('clicked');`

to

`$('li:not(#pass_settings_btn)').removeClass('clicked');`

Comment: And... this is one of those times that I hide my face in shame and prefer to begrudge my IDE for not having better ability to find syntax errors (since obviously my eye missed it). Thanks a lot; that's working great.

Comment: I don't normally use it unless I'm really stuck, but in this case, I checked over my code and just didn't see the problem, so I was wondering if it was something browser-related.

Comment: Things can be easily missed, we all do it. Several times a day, usually. I've been putting commas instead of full stops in my jQuery all day. `$('input'),val(thiswontwork)`, for example!